# Creating a new Form element in ajaxcallback function not affecting form state

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I am trying to insert new form fields into exiting wrapper within ajax callback function.

I succeeded doing so, but trying to get those new fields values inside submit function failed because they are listed in the form state values array.

How can I make their values available to be used inside the submit function.

```
$form['test'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => array('- Please select -' => [1=>'one',2=>'two']),
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => '::testSelectedCallback',
            'wrapper' => 'fields-wrapper',
            'effect' => 'fade',
            'event' => 'change',
            'progress' => array(
                'type' => 'throbber',
                'message' => NULL,
            ),
        ),
    );
$form['fields-wrapper'] = array(
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#attributes' => ['id' => 'fields-wrapper', 'class' => ['hiddenselect']],
    );

public function testSelectedCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
$form['fields-wrapper']['new_item']= array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => 'My new item',
);
$form_state->setRebuild(True);
return $form['new_item'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add fields in ajax callback functions - assuming that level2SelectedCallback() is your ajax callback (you named it something different in your form element defintion).

All form elements need to be added in the form definition. The ajax callback is only used for determining which elements need to be inserted into the page when the AJAX is returned.

Comment: never mind the name, actually I don't know the form fields type until I reach the callback sp for that reason I put the new fields inside the ajax callback

Comment: Regardless, it won't work. The form has been cached by that point, and anything not part of the cache is ignored, and on D7 at least throws an error about an 'illegal option' (not sure if the error still shows in D8 or not).

You can determine which fields to show after your ajax call in the form definition, by checking submitted values in $form_state['values']

Comment: Correct. An ajax callback will rebuild the form, you need to define it differently there and then return the new part in the ajax callback.

Comment: so is there a way to define generic form element in the form build, so its type can be decided in the ajax callback??

Comment: No, as the element will already be cached, and so cannot be altered. How is the type being determined between the form definition and the AJAX callback?

Comment: in the form building the type in null, however in the AJAX callback the type is assigned the appropriate value fetched from custom table from database

Comment: You need to fetch the form type from the database in your form definition instead.